# Replicating QGIS's mean +/- standard deviation in bash

Tags: qgis, bash, awk

My raster values range is `-82.6999969482/-5.16682815552`, so in QGIS I get `-44.9364/-23.4497` after applying the `mean +/- standard deviation` (x 2.00) like here below:

[image]

How has this been calculated?

The standard deviation value from the raster data values is `5.30047` with:

```
echo $zValues | awk '{sum+=$1; sumsq+=$1*$1}END{print sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)**2)}'
```

If I multiply the stddev's value by 2 and take it from the min/max values of the raster, the result is not `-44.9364/-23.4497`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to use the mean of the time series and then add/subtract 2 standard deviation to it.